# Unable to add a file under SDcard in Android Linux Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to add a file under Linux Android Emulator .
I followed the following procedure

```
$Android_Emulator/tools>./mksdcard -l 256M mysdcard.img
$Android_Emulator/tools>chmod 777 mysdcard.img
```

The `mysdcard.img` is created successfully with read write permissions. In android emulator Run as`>Run Configurations>Target` -- I am selecting my `emulator/avd` and  in commandsline typing

```
-sdcard "/Android_Emulator/tools/mysdcard.img
```

Answer (score 1):

after -l you should give a label name

```
> ./mksdcard -h
mksdcard: create a blank FAT32 image to be used with the Android emulator
usage: mksdcard [-l label] <size> <file>
```

Comment: Still I am facing the same issue:Error : Unable to write a read only file sytem!!